# Sphinx autodoc with Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm having issues building the module autodocs for a Django 1.4.1 project.  `make html` seems to be failing to read my docstrings because it's running into trouble importing my settings.  All of the online guides I've seen suggest using

```
import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings)
```

but this is deprecated in 1.4, and the `settings.configure()` method doesn't seem appropriate.  I haven't found nearly as much information for how to make things work in 1.4.  I tried setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS`, but no luck.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I incorrectly set a `DJANGO_SETTINGS` environment variable, when I needed to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

So, to be clear, because this info is not particularly well documented, there are two equivalent ways to setting up autodocs with Django 1.4+:

1. Set environment variables before running `make html`:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=<path to root of source>
   export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
   ```
2. Do the equivalent in `conf.py`:

   ```
   sys.path.append('<path to root of source>')
   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
   ```

I prefer the latter because I can set it in the configuration and the docs will build in any deployment.