# Sphinx-apidoc on django build html failure on `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady`

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, sphinx-apidoc

#### Question background:

I want to write documents with sphinx on my django project and auto create docs with my django code comments.

Now I have a django(1.9) project, the file structure is as below:

```
myproject/
  myproject/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  myapp/
    migrations/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
  docs/
    _build/
    _static/
    _templates/
    conf.py
    index.rst
    Makefile
```

Then, as you see, I put a `docs` folder which holds a *Sphinx* doc project inside.

Now I can edit the `*.rst` files and `build html`.

But when I tried to `autodoc` the contents, it fails.

Below is what I did:

First, I added these to the `docs/conf.py`, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969839/2544762:

```
# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
```

Then, I made a [sphinx-apidoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/invocation.html?highlight=apidoc#invocation-of-sphinx-apidoc) action:

```
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/documentation .
```

After that, in the `docs/documentations`, I got some `.rst` files:

```
myproject/
  docs/
    documentations/
      myapp.rst
      myapp.migrations.rst
      myproject.rst
      manage.rst
      modules.rst
```

After that, I run `make html`, and have the waring with:

```
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.3.3
loading translations [zh_CN]... done
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 3 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 3 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] documentation/modules                                 
/home/alfred/app/myproject/docs/documentation/core.rst:25: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'core.models'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/alfred/app/myproject/myapp/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

/home/alfred/app/myproject/docs/documentation/core.migrations.rst:10: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'core.migrations.0001_initial'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/alfred/app/myproject/myapp/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 7, in <module>
    import django.contrib.auth.models
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
/home/alfred/app/myproject/docs/documentation/myproject.rst:10: WARNING: invalid signature for automodule ('myproject.settings-sample')
/home/alfred/app/myproject/docs/documentation/myproject.rst:10: WARNING: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting 'myproject.settings-sample' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)
/home/alfred/app/myproject/docs/documentation/myproject.rst:26: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'myproject.urls'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/alfred/app/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 303, in urls
    return self.get_urls(), 'admin', self.name
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 258, in get_urls
    from django.contrib.contenttypes import views as contenttype_views
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 159, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/alfred/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... /home/alfred/app/myproject/docs/documentation/modules.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                  
generating indices... genindex py-modindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 6 warnings.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

What did I do wrong? How can I build the document with the django code?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Long time to find the solution:

In the `conf.py`, add the following:

```
import django
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
django.setup()
```

Comment: What if you don't have a settings file? Like for a django app and not a django project?

Comment: @Pawamoy you'd better make the question specifical and post another question.

Comment: In fact I found the solution: instead of setting the environment variable, import `settings` from `django.conf``and run `settings.configure(...)` before `django.setup()`

Comment: This is no option for us because setup actually calls the database connection which is not what should happen for a simple docs build.. at least not in an ideal world where the `-j 8` flag can then be used to speed up the build of the docs

Comment: @pawamoy You can create a settings file just for docs and use an in memory SQLite DB which will never actually be used.